# How to remove index.php in url ? (laravel 5.3, php 7)

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5.3

My url is like this : http://31.220.56.75/mysystem/public/index.php/login

I want remove index.php, to be like this : http://31.220.56.75/mysystem/public/login

My .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I try some tutorial di google. but I don't find the solution

**Update** :

I try update .htaccess like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's not working

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled. `a2enmod rewrite` and then reload apache service.

Comment: @Laurent Meganck, I had run it. But, It's not working

Comment: Default HTACCESS file of Laravel should work already. Any chance that you setup your virtual host incorrectly?

Comment: @Ronald, Any change in setup virtual host? How to setup my virtual host?

Comment: Add virtual host in '/etc/apache2/sites-available/00-default.host'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

default `.htaccess` in public folder should be working very fine. check: [original .htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)

Comment: Maybe his vhost config isn't pointing to the public folder. Could be the problem?

Comment: but even if it's not. it should work. it's not the .htaccess it self

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below .htaccess file, hopefully this will work.

If your are facing the issue of $_GET variable also i.e If your both URL index.php and without index.php is working but $_GET variables found not working, then the below of .htaccess code will work for you.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```